# The same table SQL Joins

Tags: sql, join, select

I have two select statements, my purpose is to display the sum of billing and the sum of penalty. Can it be done using joins?

```
SELECT SUM([Amount]) AS 'BILLING',(SELECT SUM([Amount])
                                FROM Transactions
                                WHERE CAST([TransactionDate] AS DATE)>(SELECT TOP 1 CAST([TransactionDate] AS DATE)  
                                FROM Transactions WHERE CustNo = 6313 AND [Particulars]='Payment' ORDER BY [Id] DESC) 
                                AND [CustNo]=6313 
                                AND [Particulars]='Penalty') AS 'PENALTY'
FROM Transactions
WHERE CAST([TransactionDate] AS DATE)>(SELECT TOP 1 CAST([TransactionDate] AS DATE)  
FROM Transactions WHERE CustNo = 6313 
AND [Particulars]='Payment' ORDER BY [Id] DESC) 
AND [CustNo]=6313 
AND [Particulars]='Billing'
```

Comment: Yes it can. So--Are you satisfied? What is your actual 1 specific non-duplicate question? Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [Particulars]='Billing' THEN [Amount] ELSE 0 END) AS 'BILLING',
       SUM(CASE WHEN [Particulars]='Penalty' THEN [Amount] ELSE 0 END) AS 'PENALTY',
FROM Transactions
WHERE CAST([TransactionDate] AS DATE)>(SELECT TOP 1 CAST([TransactionDate] AS DATE)  
FROM Transactions WHERE CustNo = 6313 
AND [Particulars]='Payment' ORDER BY [Id] DESC) 
AND [CustNo]=6313 
AND [Particulars]='Billing'
```